# $S_k(x+y)-S_k(x)-S_k(y)$ where $S_k$ is symmetric polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Let $S_k$ be the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial of $n$ variables. How can I rewrite $$S_k(x+y)-S_k(x)-S_k(y)$$ by just using $x,y,S_1,S_2,\cdots S_{k-1}$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$.

Example: Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$

$$S_2(x+y)-S_2(x)-S_2(y)=(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)-x_1x_2-y_1y_2$$
$$=x_1y_2+x_2y_1=(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)-(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)$$
$$=S_1(x)S_1(y)-S_1(xy).$$

How can we generalize this for any $n$ and $k$?

I believe somebody found this before but my research area is far to symmetric polynomials. References are also accepted. Thanks.

Edit: (or addition:) It can be closed form or an algorithm.. Useful comments.

Comment: What is it you want? An algorithm? A closed form?

Comment: Closed form, like in example.

Comment: This looks like $c_k(\eta\otimes\xi)-c_k(\eta)-c_k(\xi)$ for vector bundles. (Though, the $xy$ in your example is kind of cheating.) That would probably be useful in topology, but, as far as I know, no one has ever come up with a "closed formula".

Comment: I will check your method, @AlexDegtyarev. But I did it also for $k=3$, it seen a little complicated but ok. I think someone found this before.

Comment: $S_k(x+y)=\sum_{i=0}^k S_i(x)S_{k-i}(y)$, where $S_0=1$ by definition.  This is trivial from a combinatorial point of view, and also the best you'll get.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderWoo, this formula is not valid for the example in question or i am sleepy.

Comment: Oh - sorry - i misunderstood what you meant by $S_k(x+y)$.

Comment: This looks like the image of $S_k$ under the coboundary operator on Hochschild 2-cochains of the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}$, I think. Hmmmmm... but I don't know of a closed form.

Comment: But yeah, similarly to what Alex said above it may be useful to think about the cohomology of $BU$ or something.

Comment: .@vudu vucu Your _pairing_ of the two alphabets $X=\{x_i\}_{i\in I};\ Y=\{y_i\}_{i\in I}$ is not conventional (although you may need it), setting $X+Y=\{x_i+y_i\}_{i\in I}$ destroys the symmetry of the expression $S_k(X+Y)-S_k(X)-S_k(Y)$. Are you aware of this ? What is used as definition of the sum is $$X+Y=\{x_i+y_j\}_{i,j\in I}$$ In this case Alexander Woo's formula is right.

Comment: $S_k$ for the elementary symmetric functions, what a horrible notation...

Comment: Using the definitions  $x+y=(x_1+y_1,...,x_n+y_n)$ and $xy=(x_1y_1,...,x_ny_n)$ implicitely given by the OP, for the $n=3,k=3$ case I find, with the standard notation $e_i$ instead of $S_i$, $$  {e_3(x+y)-e_3(x)-e_3(y)=\\ =[e_1(x) e_1(y)-e_1(xy)][e_1(x)+e_1(y)]\\ -e_1(x)[e_1(yy)+e_2(y)]-e_1(y)[e_1(xx)+e_2(x)]\\ +e_1(xxy)+e_1(yyx)}.  $$ This may give an idea for which kind of general expression to search. Maybe the coefficient of each term is just $\pm1$ depending on the number of factors $e_i$ it contains.

Comment: I just noticed that it can be further simplified to 
$$  { \\ =e_1(x) e_2(y)+e_1(y) e_2(x)\\-e_1(xy)[e_1(x)+e_1(y)]\\ + e_1(xxy)+e_1(yyx)}.  $$ But there is a different sign rule now.

Comment: $2e_2(x)=e_1(x)^2-p_2(x)=e_1(x)^2-e_1(xx)$. There the $/2$ comes from. And now both solutions agree.

Answer (score 3):

Express $S_k$ in power sums via the Newton formula. For power sums this is the binomial formula for each summand. Then express power sums again in elementary symmetric functions.

## Added:

The expression $S_k(x+y)-S_k(x)-S_k(y)$ is still invariant under the diagonal action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S(n)$ acting on $x$ and $y$ in the same way. So it can written as a polynomial in a basis for this diagonal representation. One has to determine such a basis.
By Corollary 2.17 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/polariz.pdf) the algebra of invariant polynomials of the diagonal action is the integral closure of the the algebra of 2-polarizations of the algebra of symmetric polynomials. By Example 2.18, in the case of the permutation group, the algebra of 2-polizations is already integrally closed.

However, the expression $S_2(x+y)-S_2(x)-S_2(y)$ is a 2-polarization.

Comment: It's a good start but one has sums $\sum_i x_i^a y_i^b$ say with $a>b$ and one has to peel off the $x_i^{a-b}$ from the $(x_i y_i)^b$ somehow.

Comment: Sigh! And maybe you can't peel because the whole thing is not symmetric any more.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer. The logarithmic derivative of the generating function trick (as described very well in [Yakovlenko's notes](https://yakovenko.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/lecture5symmetry.pdf) would seem to give a reasonable approach to this (I am not quite up to working through it right this moment).

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion how to proceed in the case $k=3$, which is too long for a comment.

In case of degree $=$ number of variables $=3$ we have this formula:
\begin{align}
 & S_3(x+y+z)-S_3(x+y)-S_3(y+z)-S_3(z+y)+S_3(x)+S_3(y)+S_3(z) \\
=\;& S_1(x)S_1(y)S_1(z)-S_1(xy)S_1(z)-S_1(yz)S_1(x)-S_1(zx)S_1(y)+2S_1(xyz)
\end{align}

Specializing to $z=-\frac{x+y}{2}$ yields a formula for $S_3(x+y)-S_3(x)-S_3(y)$ in terms of $S_1$.

Comment: Have you worked it out? In my comment to the OP, there remain two $S_2$ terms. So a priori either mine or yours must be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did. Also why can't both solutions be correct?

Comment: well I think, the mean $e_2$ can only be expressed by means of $e_1$ if using reciprocals. Anyway, can you provide your final expression?

Comment: It's minus the RHS with $z$ replaced by $-\frac{x+y}{2}$. If you think an expression such as $S_1(-\frac{x+y}{2}x)$ is weird, one can write $-S_1(xx)/2-S_1(xy)/2$ instead.

Comment: In your final expression, some coefficients $1/2$ remain, which is strange. I think I've found the flaw: your formula is correct, but the problem is $S_3(2z)=8S_3(z)$ not $2S_3(z)$. So the terms of the LHS don't cancel out as you would like...

Comment: If there is a problem, it can't be that. I checked with sage that the substitution for the LHS works. Note that $S_3(x+y+z)=S_3((x+y)/2)=-S_3(z)$ which cancels the term you worry about.

Comment: yes that is true. I am puzzled... and I checked mine with Pari.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23623/discussion-between-vuur-and-wolfgang).

Answer (score 0):

I will use the standard notation $e_k$ for the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial of $n$ variables, and just $e$ instead of $e_1$ for better readability.
For $k\le n$, denote the set of the "base polynomials" of degrees $\leqslant k$ that are writable in terms of $x,y,e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_{k-1}$, possibly including coordinate-wise products as in the OP, by $P_{k-1}$.

For a partition $k=\ell+m$, define, in somewhat sloppy notation, the symmetric polynomial
$$E_{(\ell,m)}:=\sum (x_1\cdots x_\ell y_{\ell+1}\cdots y_k +y_1\cdots y_\ell x_{\ell+1}\cdots x_k ).$$
So the sum is over all pairs of disjoint $\ell$- and $m$-tuples of indices. (If $\ell=m$, each monomial occurs twice, but we will count it only once.)
For instance, the following sum has $8$ monomials, and it can be checked that we can decompose it into polynomials of $ P_{3}$ as follows:

$$E_{(3,1)}=\sum (x_1x_2x_3y_4+y_1y_2y_3x_4)=\\ e_3(x)e(y)+e_3(y)e(x)-[e_2(x)+e_2(y)]e(xy) \\ +e(x)e(xxy)+e(y)e(yyx)-e(xxxy)-e(yyyx).$$ (BTW this splits of course into two non-symmetric identities, one which contains all terms featuring three instances of $x$ and one of $y$, and the other one switching $x\leftrightarrow y$.)

Now, taking $k=4$, it is easy to see that we have $$e_k(x+y)-e_k(x)-e_k(y)=E_{(3,1)}+E_{(2,2)}$$ but it seems to me that 
$$E_{(2,2)}=\sum x_1x_2y_3y_4$$ can **not** be decomposed into polynomials of $ P_{3}$ . *Or am I wrong?*